# Fetch multiple rows from multiple models Django

Tags: django, database, model

I have this project where, I need to fetch multiple objects from multiple models in a view. I could do that by for loop but I think I shouldn't hit database in each loop. Should I use `prefetch_related`. or Should I know some other way to retrieve them.

for example:

```
class A(models.Model):
     title_name=models.CharField(...)
     id=models.AutoField(pk=True)

class B(models.Model):
     user=models.ForeignKey(User,models.ON_CASCADE=True)
     user_status=models.CharField(...)
     id=models.ForeignKey(A, models.ON_CASCADE=True)
```

I need to display `user_status, user` and associated `title_name`. I get multiple objects, `select_related` will not be useful. Any suggestions.

Comment: try to use property

Comment: Yes, you should use `prefetch_related`. There is no better way than that

Comment: @Gahan could you please tell me how to use property

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev I have tried `prefetch_related` , i couldn't exactly do what i wanted to, I've made a query something like B.objects.get(user=request.user).prefetch_related('id')

Comment: see this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046398/django-model-class-and-custom-property  you can implement function in class which you want to call in view and in property you can use function to fetch related values to your model

Comment: Also it is very bad idea to use `id` as your field name. Because django uses it to generate `primary_key`

Comment: `id` was used only here @SardorbekImomaliev ,

Comment: @Gahan thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You need make this queryset:

```
B.objects.all().select_related('user', 'id')
```

This queryset will generate sql that join user and A data from db

Next, in the model B to make a property:

```
@property
def title_name(self):
    return self.id.title_name
```

Finally you'll get queryset that makes one SQL request to database and returns all data you need.

By the way, I would rename attribute "id" in the model B to "a".

Comment: I would like to filter B objects, all() method could be costly.

Comment: @joelvarma select_related method in this case will work because id is foreign key. If you were to filter A model so you would need to use prefetch_related

Comment: Yea, i want to filter A, so how should i use `prefetch_related`